# Looking for AngularJS calendar scheduler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, calendar

I am trying to make a booking system for a ground.
Now that ground can be booked on hourly basis.
I wanted to know how can i do this with AngularJS.
Basically what I need is a calendar with week view.
And then each week should have hour wise categorization, where if we click that hour gets booked.
And similarly cancellation as well.

Answer (score 0):

The below link will show you the perfect way .
http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/